# Function returning an array of dynamically created strings in c

Tags: arrays, c, string, memory

I have a function that needs to parse a line into an array of strings. For example, if given the line

```
test1 test2 test3
```

it should return the array ["test1","test2","test3"].
I also know that all lines are maximum 81 characters.
This is my current code

```c
void parseLine(char *line, char **words){
    words = malloc(81*sizeof(char*));
    char *p = line;
    char *currentWord = (char *)calloc(strlen(line)+1,sizeof(char));
    int wordIndex = 0;
    while (*p != '\0'){
        while (isspace(*p++));
        p--;
        while (!isspace(*p) && *p != '\0'){
            strncat(currentWord,p++,1);
        }
        words[wordIndex++] = currentWord;
        currentWord = calloc(strlen(line)+1,sizeof(char));
    }
    words[wordIndex] = NULL;
}
```

My idea with this is that because I can't return a non-static array created within the function, I will use a pre-existing array. However, this doesn't work, and I think it is because the pointers to the strings are also invalidated when the function ends. I've seen some examples which make it work, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225507/return-array-of-strings), by using the "" string declaration, but such a method doesn't work for me. What can I do?

Comment: `currentWord = calloc(0,sizeof(char));` is an array of `0` elements. It cannot be used. You should use a size, like you did for `words`

Comment: I am aware, but that part works just as intended even with the weird array declaration. If I look at the array before I leave the function, everything is parsed correctly, the problems start when I leave the function. Nevertheless I will change that

Comment: "*that part works*". No it doesn't. It is wrong and needs to be fixed. You are writing to invalid memory and that results in Undefined Behaviour. And changing it from 0 to 1 doesn't help much. It needs to be big enough to fit the entire string.

Comment: No it doesn't, the strncat should handle it as far as I understand

Comment: Wait, I am now looking it up, and I'm completely wrong. I'll fix it

Comment: No it doesn't. strncat does not increase the buffer size for you. The way you call it will result in 1 byte being added to the end of `currentWord` each time `strncat` is called. But you have only allocated 1 byte for the string so writing any thing longer than an empty string to it will result in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Ok, I think I fixed it, still the same general problem though.

Comment: `strlen(line)` ==> `strlen(line) + 1` for the 0-terminator.

Comment: I am passing in char **words in the parameters I think

Comment: The return value somehow fixed it, I don't fully understand, but it works now. Thanks!

Comment: Just how memory efficient is this program? Which pointers will I need to free up after I call the function?

Comment: @PlainXYZ It's very inefficient. Both memory and time wise.